# How to sign in to my microsoft account without it replacing my local account?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft-account, microsoft

I just got a new SSD and new windows on it. There's currently no OneDrive, or Office, or other Microsoft services on it. So I want to sign in to my Microsoft account on this laptop because of that.

However I also want to retain my local account with my local password. I like having a simple name and a simple password to my physical laptop, so that accessing it is fast and easy.

The only thing I can see currently is `"Sign in with a Microsoft account instead"` under `Your Info` in the settings. But wouldn't that replace my local account with my Microsoft one? I don't want that to happen. I'm honestly kinda lost, since I tried looking up answers to my questions on google but the answers I found were either always mixed, or from Microsoft itself which wants me to replace my local account anyway.

What can I do to have a Microsoft account on windows and retain my local account username and password?

Answer (score 1):

The local account and the Microsoft Account are different accounts with different user profiles. That may account for part of the confusion about this.

Go to Start, Settings, Accounts and make a New Account. Set this account up as a Microsoft Account.

This will not affect the Local Account (it will still remain) but the two accounts are different and do not share documents.

You can copy the documents / email and so on from the local account to the Microsoft Account using a third Admin Account.

I have both Local and Microsoft Accounts on my own machine.

If you want everything in a Microsoft Account that is in your local account, then you must convert it and the local account disappears.

I have converted a local account as well and that process works fine. There is no disadvantage from using a Microsoft Account.

If you have both accounts working, they will show up in a list at sign on. Otherwise, the main account will be pre-filled and all you have to enter is password or a PIN.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sign-in to your Microsoft account in Windows.
You may elect to use a local Windows account, but sign-in to the
Microsoft account on the apps only, such as on the Microsoft Store.
This is actually what I do on my computer.

You may create a Microsoft account from the bottom of the page
[Sign In or Create Your Account Today](https://account.microsoft.com/account/manage-my-account).
Look for the link to click that is named "Create an account".

Once the account is created, you may use it everywhere, even for Windows
if eventually you decide to
("Sign in with a Microsoft account instead").